# Elasticsearch - Test new analyzers against an existing data set

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

New to Elasticsearch.

I need to update an index to treat both plurals & singulars as matches. So `green apple` should match `green apples` and well (and vice versa).

Through my research, I understand I need to *recreate the index* with a `stemmer` filter.

So:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "std_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [ "stemmer" ]
    }
  }
}
```

1. Can anyone confirm if the above is correct? If not, what will I need to use?
2. I also understand that I cannot modify the existing index, but rather I will need to create a new one with this analyzer, and then re-add all the documents to the new index. Is that correct? If so, is there a shortcut or easy way to tell it to "add all documents from index X to new index Y?"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find inline answers

1. In most of the cases, it should work, and also its really difficult to cover all the future use-cases and in your case we don't even know your current use-cases, you can use [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) and test some of your use-case, before pushing these analyzer related changes to production.*
2. Adding/changing the Analyzer is a breaking change as it controls how the tokens are generated and indexed in the elasticsearch inverted index, hence **you have to create reindex all the documents with updated Analyzer setting, you can use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) with
   alias to do it with zero down time.**

Comment: @Elasticsearch_Ninja thank you for pointing me to these! Makes perfect sense. Could you also tell me, do I need to specifically add `"analyzer" : "std_analyzer"` to all my keyword mappings, or it it implied that this will be used when searching any keyword if the index was created with this?

Comment: Well, I posted a similar follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574089/elasticsearch-choosing-the-analyzer-to-use-for-fields

Comment: @Ricky glad it helped, I answered your question and will be adding more details